# File that don't have thumbnail image throws COM Exception in Win 8 Metro

Tags: c#, thumbnails, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

In my application, I need to grab the thumbnail image from files picked using File Picker. The following line throws COM exception when File Picker returns a file that does not have a thumbnail image such as an empty *.bmp file. How do I avoid this?

```
 StorageItemThumbnail t = await f.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.DocumentsView);
```

EDIT: additional details and I meant .bmp not .png sorry...

To reproduce:

1. Right click in any directory in Metro desktop mode, in the context menu click New->Bitmap Image
2. In a test program, launch File Picker, then call GetThumbnailAsync on that file returned; you get the exception below.

Exception Details:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled by user code
>
> HResult=-2147467259
>   Message=Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned
>   from a call to a COM component.
>   Source=mscorlib
>   ErrorCode=-2147467259   StackTrace:
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   ---some stuff ommitted---
>   InnerException: null

Code to launch the File Picker:

```
public static async Task<IReadOnlyList<StorageFile>> PickMulipleFilesAsync()
    {
        FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        var files = await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

        return files;
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact COM Exception that you are seeing..???

Comment: DP or CP?  It matters because a number of marshaling issues have been resolved in the CP.

Comment: Document your question better, quote the *exact* exception details.  PNGs cannot be empty.

Comment: Added more detail. My current workaround: I silently catch the exception and check if the StorageItemThumbnail returned was null, then I can put a placeholder image in my UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in above comments and also by someone on MSDN forums. A workaround is simply the call to GetThumbnailAsync in a in a try-catch block and put a placeholder image when there is no thumbnail.

```
StorageItemThumbnail t=null;
BitmapImage thumbnailImage= new BitmapImage();//image used for display
try{    
    t = await f.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.DocumentsView);
}
catch(Exception e){
    t = null;
}
if (null == t)
    thumbnailImage = placeholder;//no thumbnail then use the placeholder image
else 
    thumbnailImage.SetSource(t);
```